# How can i smoothly playback a FLV at different speeds?

Tags: flash, flv

I will need to display the frames of an FLV at different rates.

Here are some examples:

- the user will 'scrub' through the flv frames(front/back)
- the flv will need to play at half the speed on a user interaction.

Currently I'm using [LoaderMax](http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/) and it's VideoLoader object to load and play FLV files.
I've tried using the [playProgress](http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/loading/VideoLoader.html#playProgress) property, but only the keyframes of the FLV are displayed. I got the same result with the basic setup(using the NetStream class)

As a workaround, I playback the FLV once, and cache BitmapData instances in which I draw/cache each frame of the video. After this is done, I use the BitmapData Vector to update a Bitmap on stage. Scrubbing/changing speed works fine with this method, but still the user needs to see(wait for) the sequence once, while it gets cached, which I don't like.

Any better ideas on how to do this ?

Any tips are useful,
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are making a web-based video editor. While I hope someone has a useful answer for you, I suspect you will need something other than flash. Perhaps there is a way to wrap VLC in a browser plugin.

Comment: @Brad it's nowhere near a web-based video editor. It's part of a 'rich media' website that will have some nice pre-rendered content that will need to be controlled interactively by the users.

Comment: @George Profenza - I've seen this done before but the video was imported into the flash ide and we manipulated the time line for the scrubbing.  I believe we had a second version of the video for the slow motion play back version and switched between the two movieclips. Fairly low-tech method and wasn't without it's issues but we got round them. I have a feeling you're going to struggle to do this with a plain old flv using progressive download

Comment: @James Hay - Thank you very much for the input. I've done some similar a few years ago, since playing back a timeline forwards with an embedded video was fine, but backwards was interpolating horribly. You are right, the issue I'm having is with progressive flv download. I would prefer using a single flv instead of two, but still it's a pretty good technique. The timeline method would work for changing the speed of the video, but not the direction with a single video.

Comment: @George Profenza - Fair shout. Sorry I couldn't help more :) . Good luck!

Comment: @James Hay Your method is good nevertheless and it should be posted as an answer so I can vote it :)

Comment: @George Profenza - lol, more of a work around but I'll copy it in for the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this done before but the video was imported into the flash ide and we manipulated the time line for the scrubbing. I believe we had a second version of the video for the slow motion play back version and switched between the two movieclips. Fairly low-tech method and wasn't without it's issues but we got round them. I have a feeling you're going to struggle to do this with a plain old flv using progressive download.

Answer (score 2):

Thx for the question: it made me read [flv format spec (from page 74)](http://download.macromedia.com/f4v/video_file_format_spec_v10_1.pdf) and start writing a `ByteArray` based parser. as far as i understood there're two ways:

> Body VideoTagBody The VideoTagBody
>   contains the video frame payload.

so it seems possible to access each frame as pixel data
another one is to set framerate in metadata to a value you like, write an flv back to ByteArray and save to local filesystem or use [`NetStream.appendBytes()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#appendBytes%28%29) for playback

Comment: so, would it be possible in theory to access the flv as a byte array and accessing the video frame payload, either close pixel data from each frame and add it in reverse order at the end of the original video payload and update the metaData in the header of the file, or clone the flv as a byte array, reverse the clone's 'frames' and create a feed that to a new NetStream ?

Comment: @ George Profenza - i thought mostly about editing and retrieving/changing frames and saving back, but at this point i made too little research to know for sure. i'll let you know when i get the results. BTW about two hours ago i found a similar package in OSMF (`package org.osmf.net.httpstreaming.flv`) however i go on coding :)

Comment: @ George Profenza - FlashDevelop dies when i try to trace a full list of tags of a 6 second flv. maybe it's because i trace all SCRIPTDATA tags however

Comment: @www0z0k Thank you! Wish I could give you more votes for your effort!

Comment: @ George Profenza - welcome) it was rather easy to get an array of tags from an .flv, but now i have to study all that audio and video codecs specs to gain desired access to media data. feel lazy but interested so i hope it'll be done

Comment: @www0z0k That sounds great! Keep me up to date when you've made some progress please. Thanks!

Comment: @ George Profenza - if you play video from FMS - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#step%28%29 might be useful. btw do you know where to get full `Sorenson H.263 for flv` spec? i'm trying to use http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf (from page 236) but it's really hard to merge adobe description with the original spec.