# How to loop part of a Flash movie backward and forward ("ping-pong" loop)

Tags: flash, video, actionscript, flv

I have a Flash movie with two embedded FLV videos in it. What I would like to do is when the page loads, the movie plays through both video clips...then when it reaches the end of the second one, it switches and plays in reverse until the beginning of the second clip, then plays to the end again - essentially a "ping-pong" loop for the second half of the timeline.

I've looked at a few different solutions, but they're all for use with buttons and seem too complex. I would hope that what I want to do is quite simple, and would require only a few lines of code.

Here's what I'm currently working with, but it's not working (it's been a long time since I used AS, so I'm sure I've missed something obvious). Frame 171 is where the second clip starts, and frame 230 is where the movie ends.

```
function mcPlay(_root, 171) {
    if (f == 230) {
        f = _root._totalframes;
    }
    _root.onEnterFrame = function() {
        var cf:Number = this._currentframe;
        if (cf == f) {
            delete this.onEnterFrame;
        } else if (cf<f) {
            this.nextFrame();
        } else {
            this.prevFrame();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: also you need to watch out with [flv and playing backwards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496066/how-can-i-smoothly-playback-a-flv-at-different-speeds). if it runs choppy in reverse and sound isn't an issue, you might want to create an array of BitmapData objects onto which you cache the flv's contents (using draw()) once at the begining, then scrub though the BitmapData objects. non-code version would be to use an image sequence version of your flv file

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code you need, one important note for this to work: put the code in a 1-frame movieclip and not on the main video timeline:

```
var direction:String = "forward";

_root.onEnterFrame = function()
{
    if (direction == "forward")
    {
        if (_root._currentframe == _root._totalframes)
        {
            trace("switch to back")
            _root.stop()
            direction = "back";
        }
    }
    else if (direction == "back")
    {
        if (_root._currentframe == 171)
        {
            trace("switch to forward")
            direction = "forward";
            _root.play();
        }
        else
            _root.prevFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: another way would be something like this:`var direction:Number = 1;

onEnterFrame = function():Void
{
 if(_currentframe == _totalframes || _currentframe == 171) direction *= -1;//flip the direction
 gotoAndStop(_currentframe + direction);
}`

Comment: I haven't gotten this working yet. I switch to AS2 since it includes _root, but all the movie does is loop the clip like normal. I see "switch to back" firing, but not "switch to forward." I have the FLV embedded in a movie clip at 170 frames long, the code in a separate layer above it also 170 frames long, and in the main timeline the movie clip is on one frame with a "stop();" action on a separate layer. Am I missing something?